# Symfony2 Install Failing- Error 1866 (attribute 'path' is not allowed) / FileLoaderLoadException (Cannot import resource)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install a pre-made dev environment using vagrant. The last component is symfony2. The console is throwing up an error (given below). Any ideas on what the fix could be? I've tried googling them with no luck. Thanks for any insights!

**Install Log:**

```
==> default: 
==> default:                                                                                                                                                                        
==> default:   [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                         
==> default:   Cannot import resource "/srv/wealthbot/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml" from "/srv/wealthbot/app/config/routing.yml".  
==> default:                                                                                                                                                                        
==> default: 
==> default:                                                                                                                                                                    
==> default:   [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                       
==> default:   [ERROR 1866] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/routing}route', attribute 'path': The attribute 'path' is not allowed. (in /srv/wealthbot/ - line 6, column 0)  
==> default:                                                                                                                                                                    
==> default: 
==> default: cache:warmup [--no-optional-warmers]
==> default: Warming up the cache for the prod environment with debug false
==> default:
```

**The routing.xml from /srv/wealthbot/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_js_routing_js" path="/js/routing.{_format}">
        <default key="_controller">fos_js_routing.controller:indexAction</default>
        <default key="_format">js</default>
        <requirement key="_format">js|json</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**The routing.yml from /srv/wealthbot/app/config/ :**

```
# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#    prefix:   /_internal
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_group:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/group.xml"
    prefix: /group

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/doc
```

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: This is the set of components and versions specified as "require" in the main composer.json. The installation script runs composer install --prefer-source.

https://gist.github.com/sidatgt/b216533b1ad7cef630286f550c17f79e

Comment: Quick update: I see now that this error gets triggered by the cache clear and warmup commands in the install script. This is the install script: https://gist.github.com/sidatgt/1db49d813937ea6cc11d058621d04d9d There are 4 cache commands, and each of them triggers the same errors re. invalid arguments in routing.xml

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2.1 (which by the way dropped support a long time ago) did not have the `path` attribute for routes. You had to use the `pattern` attribute then.